# Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView

Tags: android, mapbox

Application throws a `view.InflateException` while opening `MapBox`, in API 19. This is the error:

```
12-06 11:59:22.057 2906-2906/com.example.sabith.doortracker E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to 
start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sabith.doortracker/com.example.sabith.doortracker.view.admin.WorkPolylineActivity}:
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:621)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
 at com.example.sabith.doortracker.view.admin.WorkPolylineActivity.onCreate(WorkPolylineActivity.java:71)
 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:595)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697) 
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756) 
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
 at com.example.sabith.doortracker.view.admin.WorkPolylineActivity.onCreate(WorkPolylineActivity.java:71) 
 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/maps/widgets/MyLocationView
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:595)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:462)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
 at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView.initialise(MapView.java:125)
 at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:102)
```

build.gradle :

```
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:5.2.0@aar'
//Mapbox webkit Library
compile('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:4.2.1@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
```

layout.xml:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:mapbox="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
        <com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/mapViewPolyline"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            mapbox:mapbox_styleUrl="@string/mapbox_style_mapbox_streets"
            mapbox:mapbox_cameraZoomMin="6"
            mapbox:mapbox_uiRotateGestures="false"/>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

But, application run smoothly on API greater than 19.

Please suggest a solution.

Comment: check your XML.

Comment: @KuLdipPaTel, Applcation run smootly on API greater than 19

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OP issue was fixed via https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/pull/10579 and it'll be available in the upcoming release `5.2.1`.

In the meantime, you could test this out with the `5.3.0-SNAPSHOT` build which includes the fix.

To use snapshots, you'd need to add the snapshots repo in the root `build.gradle` file:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    }
}
```

In your app `build.gradle` you'd need to replace your current dependency with:

```
implementation(com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:5.3.0-SNAPSHOT@aar) {
        transitive = true
}
```

Hope that helps! Cheers!

Comment: Cheers bro, Thank you

Comment: For non snapshot versions use :

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/" }
    }

Answer (score 0):

For non-snapshot versions use :

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/" }
}
```